# Can't ping default gateway but have internet connection

Tags: routing, router, subnet, ping

I am connected to a distant box in my vlan using ssh (This openwrt box is in cascade with a router).

When I ping the default gateway, it won't work:

```
route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.14.164.126   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Ping:

```
ping 10.14.164.126
PING 10.14.164.126 (10.14.164.126): 56 data bytes
^C
--- 10.14.164.126 ping statistics ---
11 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

At the same time traceroute is using the default gateway and it can go out to reach Internet:

```
traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (173.194.40.128), 30 hops max, 38 byte packets
 1  10.14.164.126 (10.14.164.126)  0.359 ms  0.706 ms  0.349 ms
 2  172.24.120.93 (172.24.120.93)  2.318 ms  2.809 ms  2.417 ms
..etc
```

I would like to know why the ping is not working !

Comment: NE is a site to ask and provide answers about professionally managed networks. Your question appears to fall outside the areas that our community decided are on topic. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details. You could try posting this on a different site on the network, such as [su].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your default gateway configured to respond to pings?

If you can ping through the DG (eg. to google.com) but can't ping it, then the routing is fine.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Your default gateway is cofigured to block all ICMP messages including ping but to allow other traffic to cross its outside interface.

Answer (score -1):

Yep I agree ICMP message blocks are being used in this instance.